# Sending request to a Client from Server GUI - Java

Tags: java, user-interface, client, server

I have a `Server-Client` application where n number of clients are connected to the Server. I have two question which I'm not able to get answers.

1.Assign the Clients to a `JButton` in Server so that when we click the button we can send request to it.

2.How do I run a method in `Client` when the `JButton` of that particular Client is clicked in the Server GUI.

Comment: 1- Probably use a `JTable` or `JList` instead; 2- You send a message back to the client via the sever side `Socket` by which the client connected.

Comment: Does each client have an assigned SessionID that the server can see? If not, then perhaps you could generate a sessionID and create a socket with that sessionID to communicate with specific users.

Comment: How do I generate sessionID?